# Ghostscript not rendering ligatures PDF->PNG

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am using ghostscript 9.54 on windows. Goal is to convert a PDF to a PNG which should be sent to a printer; it must not have any anti-aliasing since the printout will be blurry.
If I use gs to convert the PDF file, the letters look really ugly, e.g.:
[image: Ugly letters]

If I disable FAPI (-dDisableFAPI=true), the letters look nice:

[image: Nice letters]

The problem with disabled FAPI is when the PDF contains ligatures; conversion will fail and the particular text block having a ligature is missing in the output, although the font is embedded in the PDF.
Used font is nimbus san L con; same problem with arial.

1. Is there a way to use FAPI rendering but produce the same "nice" output as the legacy rendering? Disable FAPI has been deprectated many years ago...
2. If not, can I force GS to use the embedded font / the windows font which has the needed ligatures? Adding the font path to the command line makes GS use the windows font only if the font is not known by GS, as far as I understood; however, nimbus comes with GS.
3. If not: does anybody know a PDF library (.NET on windows) that can do nice rasterization without anti alias? I tried already a lot of them, but found none that really has nice output (they all produce output like in the "ugly" example which looks really awkward after printout).

Steps to reproduce: use Indesign to create a document with two textboxes, on having the content "USA", one having the content "fl". Export to PDF. Use gs to convert to png. With DisableFAPI=true, the "fl" is missing in the output; otherwise, it is there, but the letters are really ugly.
It works if you disable ligatures in Indesign, but this is not an option.

Used command line:

```
gswin64c -dDisableFAPI=true -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -o C:\Temp\test.png C:\Temp\test.pdf
```

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to guess what's going on without seein the Ghostscript input file. Don't use DisableFAPI=true, as you say, it is deprecated, and will likely be removed Real Soon Now(tm)! If the font you are using is a TrueType, you could try adding "-dGridFitTT=2".

Comment: The input is a pdf file with a text "flying high", the "fl" being a ligature character (e.g. Indesign does this by default). I have a demo file but don't know at the moment how to provide it here. You are right, DisableFAPI is deprecated, but without, the letters are so ugly :-(

Comment: We (Ghostscript) have a bug tracker where you can report problems and attach files: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/

Comment: Done: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=703785